# npm ERR Refusing to install package with name <packageName> under a package also called <packageName>

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I am trying to use the [jsonfile](https://github.com/jprichardson/node-jsonfile) package in my project, but I get the following errors:

1. `Refusing to install package with name <packagename> under a package also called <packagename>.` (Note that none of the directory or filename is same as package name)
2. `Cannot find module <packagename>.`

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The problem is caused when the name of project in `package.json` is the same as the module you're trying to install.

To solve this problem, please change the project name in `package.json` to something else. For example, "jsonfile-test":

```
{
  "name": "jsonfile-test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I thought I had to physically rename my work-space directory. This approach saved the day.

Answer (score -1):

I think it should be:

```
npm install --save json-file
```

not

```
npm install --save jsonfile
```

ref:  https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-file

If that does not work please try enabling permissions install - e.g. (on mac- but will be equivalent on windows, check: https://helpdeskgeek.com/free-tools-review/5-windows-alternatives-linux-sudo-command/) run:

```
sudo npm install --save json-file
```

Comment: probably should not sudo install. Instead, use `npm config edit` to set `prefix` to a directory that does not require root permissions. On mac/unix, this will be `$HOME`/`~`