# npm install ws fails on MacOS big sur

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, websocket

I tried to install websocket via " npm install ws" , but it always returned

```
npm ERR! code ENOSELF
npm ERR! Refusing to install package with name "ws" under a package
npm ERR! also called "ws". Did you name your project the same
npm ERR! as the dependency you're installing?
npm ERR!
npm ERR! For more information, see:
npm ERR! https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install#limitations-of-npms-install-algorithm

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! /Users/croydon/.npm/_logs/2021-03-18T00_55_40_611Z-debug.log
```

please could you help on how to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Share your package.json. change "name" key in your package.json something else other than "ws".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [npm ERR Refusing to install package with name <packageName> under a package also called <packageName>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52179949/npm-err-refusing-to-install-package-with-name-packagename-under-a-package-also)

Comment: I modified package.json to. {
  "name": "",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "ws": "^7.4.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}

Comment: rerun npm install ws

Comment: npm WARN  #1.0.0 No description
npm WARN #1.0.0 No repository field.

+ ws#7.4.4
added 1 package from 1 contributor and audited 1 package in 1.333s
found 0 vulnerabilities

Comment: In the application js code. const WebSocket = require('ws'); but new WebSocket('ws://webhost') still fails. I tested the ws://webhost using chrome websocket plugin, it returns success.  How to check if ws being correctly installed?

Answer (score 0):

I've only been successful installing ws globally.
Note that the old way of installing globally is deprecated.
You will get an error message with instructions if you try it.
The new way:

```
npm install --location=global ws
```

Comment: The issue with OP was that they named their project "ws" as well, and they solved the problem by renaming it. If you have an issue with installing `ws` due to other reasons, you should probably create a new question.

Comment: You should try it yourself before commenting.

Comment: I've worked on plenty of projects that use `ws` as a local dependency (either directly or as a dependency-of-a-dependency, for example `socket.io`). You don't explain _why_ you can only get it to work when its installed globally, but there's nothing inherent to that package that requires it to be installed globally.